How to unnest nested JSON data in SQL columns or with Python?
I'm working with a table that contains both standard data types (like strings and integers) and nested JSON data in some columns. Here's an example of the table structure:
| id | event_name  | event_params                                   |
|----|-------------|------------------------------------------------|
| 1  | Item1       | [{key=name_attribute1, value={...}}, {...}]    |
| 2  | Item2       | [{key=name_attribute2, value={...}}, {...}]    |


The nested data in the 'event_params' column follows exactly this structure:
'[{key=name_attribute1, value={string_value=some-string, int_value=null, float_value=null, double_value=null}}, {key=name_attribute2, value={string_value=some-value, int_value=null, float_value=null, double_value=null}}, {...}, {...}]'

(there are many dicts, with different keys in these columns, and there are keys that just appear in some rows)
I want to unnest these data to create new columns for each key while retaining the data from the non-nested columns. Ideally, I would like to achieve this in SQL. However, if that's not feasible, I'm open to using Python as well.
Could someone please guide me on how to transform this nested structure into a flat table format either directly in SQL or using Python?
Thanks in advance for your help!
What i tried?
I tried do unnest the data using SQL, but it duplicate the lines.
What i expect?
I expect to have a table like this, with unnest data tranformed into columns. Important: I do not need every key, just selected ones.
| id | event_name  | name_attribute1    | name_attribute2      | name_attribute_n
|----|-------------|--------------------|----------------------|------------------
| 1  | Item1       | some_string        | some_string          | ...
| 2  | Item2       | some_string        | some_string          | ...



In which format do you have the table? As posted in the question in text form?

The columns in the provided table example don't contain valid JSON data ...

You can use panda's json_normalize like this: df = pd.json_normalize(data)

You can use schema_of_json to automatically determine schema and parse json columns. Unnesting then is very easy with dot operator. https://stackoverflow.com/a/78292935/3238085

I am not sure what the format under the table is, but I imagine that it is a parquet or CSV format. I access this table through AWS Athena, using the AWS data catalog (the company are using data mesh architecture). I know that the JSON I showed is not valid JSON data (like using "=", instead of ":"). But it is the format that I see when I make SELECT * FROM table_name. When I tried to download the data, the nested columns came in the exatcly format that I show.

I've tried using 'json_normalize', but since the JSON is not valid, it doesn't work.
